# Three.js cannot load materials (Cannot read property 'length' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I'm still learning three.js, and I've bumped into an issue that's preventing me from progressing.

I've searched for days, but couldn't find an answer that would be helpful to me, for some reason.

The issue is that I cannot import a JSON model's materials. I get the "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" all the time, and I cannot understand why.

The code I'm using to import is pretty simple, and is as follows:

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load( "island.json", function ( geometry, materials ) {
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );
    scene.add( mesh );
    render();
} );
```

The JSON file I'm trying to import is massive, therefore I've made a much smaller sample which also happens to run into the same error. [Here it is](http://hastebin.com/odirivosew.apache)

Hopefuly you guys can help me out!

Massive thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JSON` code is not the issue, but rather, you are mixing up `JSONLoader` and `ObjectLoader`.

`JSONLoader` and `ObjectLoader` both accept JSON, but they are structured differently. Do this instead:

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load("island.json", function(object){
    scene.add(object);
});
```

See more here: http://helloenjoy.com/2013/from-unity-to-three-js/